# How to put response of an AJAX in SPAN?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

i want to post an `input` and `select` to an php site using `ajax` and get the result displayed in a `span` using the success function.

After searching, I can't get it really done, below is my code so far:

```
<span id="span_to_post_response"></span>


$(document).on("click", "#btn_to_click", function () {
    var form_to_send_in_var = $("#form_to_serialize").serialize();
    $.post('<?php echo base_url();?>api/mySite',form_to_send_in_var);

});
```

Where do I put my success function?

Comment: Did you try giving an extra argument to $.post? https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: as mentioned above, $.post takes a 3rd argument, which is the "success"  callback. Try reading the documentation.

Comment: @ADyson i know it does, but where in my snippet?

Comment: @Cyber as the 3rd argument when you call $.post. Just like any other parameter/argument that you pass to a function! `$.post('<?php echo base_url();?>api/mySite',form_to_send_in_var, function(data) { jQuery('#span_to_post_response').text(data);
            });` Looks like the accepted answer has shown you a different version, but the idea is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `.post` function,Try using something like this

```
jQuery.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo base_url();?>api/mySite',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                // Send the data you want
                // email: jQuery('.address').val()
            },
            success: function(data){
                jQuery('#span_to_post_response').text(data);
            },
            error: function() {
                jQuery('#span_to_post_response').text('Sorry, an error occurred.');
            }
        });
```

Comment: Where is the button click event?

Comment: use something lie 
`$("#button_id").on('click',function(){
//above thing here
})`